# Rank of Matrix Product

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I prove that $rank(AB) \le min(rank(A), rank(B))$?

I got the first way (that it is less than $rank(A)$ because $AB$ is a subset of $C(A)$), but how do I get that it is less than $rank(B)$?

Comment: How do you define the rank of two matrices? The rank of the union of their column spaces?

Comment: @TedShifrin That's what I thought.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

One approach (if you know nullity-rank) is to look at the nullspaces (kernels) of $B$ and $AB$. Another approach is to realize that $C(AB)$ is spanned by the vectors you obtain by taking a basis for $C(B)$ and applying $A$ to those vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (thanks to Monahan's *A Primer on Linear Models*):

$$r(AB)=r(B^TA^T)$$

Comment: This relies on the (somewhat) deep result that $\text{rank}(C) = \text{rank}(C^\top)$.